# Symfony2 reverse proxy returns "stale invalid"

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Symfony2 reverse proxy cache is enabled with the following settings(testing in the dev environment):

```
class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'debug'                  => true,
            'default_ttl'            => 20,
            'private_headers'        => array(),
            'allow_reload'           => false,
            'allow_revalidate'       => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 21,
            'stale_if_error'         => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

The responses from the server are following.

From the first request(as expected):

```
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/posts?pageNumber=1: miss, store
```

From the second request and all subsequent requests within 20 seconds(as expected, content being served from cache):

```
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/posts?pageNumber=1: fresh
```

From the requests after 20 seconds(problematic):

```
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/posts?pageNumber=1: stale, invalid
```

With the **stale, invalid** response, I get response not from the reverse proxy cache, but from the server that going through MVC cycle.

Feels like a couple things failed here:

- Stale content is not being served from cache;
- Cache is not being revalidated;

Any ideas where to look for a cause?

Answer (score 1):

This looks normal in my eyes.

You mention that it is problematic that stale content is being served from the cache. However,  this is normal behaviour. 'Stale' means that the content surpassed its ttl (time to live) and should not be served from the cache anymore. Therefore the server is hit again, to get fresh content and repopulate the cache.

Comment: In my understanding, stale content still should be served from cache, while repopulate the cache with a fresh content. The problem is the cache never gets repopulated. Content continues to be served from the server after initial ttl expires.