# Does Symfony2 Gateway Cache support "stale-while-revalidate" extension?

Tags: php, symfony, caching

In the [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony2-reverse-proxy) there is a reference to stale-while-revalidate:

```
// app/AppCache.php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'debug'                  => false,
            'default_ttl'            => 0,
            'private_headers'        => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
            'allow_reload'           => false,
            'allow_revalidate'       => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
            'stale_if_error'         => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

---

However I can't achieve the following behaviour([described here](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2007/12/12/stale)) with the Symfony2 Gateway cache:

[image]

---

I'm using pretty much default config. I'm getting the following responses:

On first request, response was from the server (took 300ms).

```
Age:0
Cache-Control:public, s-maxage=20
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/boards/kQVhc2uJ: miss, store
```

On second request, response was from the gateway cache (took 30ms).

```
Age:4
Cache-Control:public, s-maxage=20
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/boards/kQVhc2uJ: fresh
```

On third request, response was from the server (took 300ms).

```
Age:0
Cache-Control:public, s-maxage=20
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /api/boards/kQVhc2uJ: stale, invalid, store
```

I would expect the third request to be returned from the gateway cache and gateway cache to make an async call to the server to revalidate the cache. Instead I get a direct call to the server pass the gateway cache.

Does Symfony2 Gateway Cache supports "state-while-revalidate" extension? Or it's only useful with Squid or Varnish?

Comment: I've asked a more specific question to my case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444320/symfony2-reverse-proxy-returns-stale-invalid This is an attempt to ask a more direct Symfony-related question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **partially**. @jakzal comment from the [Github issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10599#issuecomment-39147273):

> @websirnik there won't be an async call with the HttpCache. If there was a response stored before, which is no longer fresh, the first request will generate a new response. If there are any other requests during that time they will be served a stale response.
>
> HttpCache is a simple reverse proxy and it doesn't intend to replace varnish or squid.